# How to ask a user to rate your cocos2dx game android

Tags: cocos2d-x

I developed my game in cocos2d-x C++ ,done Rating an game functionality using "AppiRater" for iOS, it works very well thanks for the library. 
Now i am porting my game to android. Now i cannot use obj-C written AppiRater for android . Is there any library like Appirater written in c++ or else i Please direct me in right direction  thanks in Advance.

Comment: we need to add appirater in appcontroller or appdelegate.. if i add  in appcontroller "instancevariable _delegate accesed in class method " error appears.  what way u integrated. plz share the steps.

Answer (score 0):

i found answer myself https://github.com/drewjw81/appirater-android

use this API .It was in java. Follow the given steps

1. Include the AppiraterAndroid library in your project
2. Right click your projects properties -> Library section just click add and select the      appirater-android library

3.Copy the /res/values/appirater-settings.xml from the AppiraterAndroid library in to your   projects /res/values/ folder and adjust the settings to your preference.
eg: your app name,and the market URL ,etc

In appirater.settings .xml change "appirator_test_mode" to true so Rate pop up will appear
every time app launches

4.In your project.java (src/org.cocos2dx/project/project.java) file

public class puffingFrenzy extends Cocos2dxActivity{

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Appirater.appLaunched(this);   // ADD this line here
}

static {
     System.loadLibrary("game");
}
```

}

I had a linker error ,Appirater file not found ,even though it was included in ADT.
   Right click project->properties->android->in library section add the path of Appirater-android master ->click ok

build and run .its better to run on device than emulator(emulator takes time)